# No sound in kodi after upgrade to Fedora 30

Tags: audio, fedora, kodi

I run Fedora Server on my htpc (Intel NUC7i3BNK). It has no desktop environment installed, it just starts xinit and the kodi-standalone binary. Until today this worked like a charm. But today I upgraded to Fedora 30 and have no sound since then.

The first error was, that kodi did not start anymore, which was fixed by installing kodi. It seems that kodi was removed during the upgrade. It starts again now, but I get no sound.

I have red a lot of articles already on how to fix that, but none of them helped.

A lot of the articles recommend to use pulseaudio, but I would like to avoid that, as it worked without pulse until now.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So, I kind of solved the problem.
I actually did nothing.

I wanted to backup kodi's files and reinstall with Fedora 29, so I booted the system and the sound worked again.
I hate it when that happens.

Comment: Have you checked kodi documentation to confirm they support Fedora 30 and what, if any, the upgrade path or process should be?